# With the Kraken Python REST API, how to interact with Sandbox/demo environment?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, demo, kraken.com

I want to use a Python 3.9 client with the Kraken REST API.  I'm using the codebase they posted here -- https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025180232-REST-API-command-line-client-Python-.  I would like to test the calls, so I recently created an API key at https://demo-futures.kraken.com/ .  What I'm having trouble with, is figuring out what the demo API URL is.  Specifically, I want to use this code

```
api_domain = "https://api.kraken.com"

...
if api_method in api_private or api_method in api_trading or api_method in api_funding or api_method in api_staking:
    api_path = "/0/private/"
    api_nonce = str(int(time.time()*1000))
    try:
        api_key = open("API_Public_Key").read().strip()
        api_secret = base64.b64decode(open("API_Private_Key").read().strip())
    except:
        print("API public key and API private (secret) key must be in plain text files called API_Public_Key and API_Private_Key")
        sys.exit(1)
    api_postdata = api_data + "&nonce=" + api_nonce
    api_postdata = api_postdata.encode('utf-8')
    api_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(api_nonce.encode('utf-8') + api_postdata).digest()
    api_hmacsha512 = hmac.new(api_secret, api_path.encode('utf-8') + api_method.encode('utf-8') + api_sha256, hashlib.sha512)
    api_request = urllib.request.Request(api_domain + api_path + api_method, api_postdata)
    api_request.add_header("API-Key", api_key)
    api_request.add_header("API-Sign", base64.b64encode(api_hmacsha512.digest()))
    api_request.add_header("User-Agent", "Kraken REST API")
elif api_method in api_public:
    api_path = "/0/public/"
    api_request = urllib.request.Request(api_domain + api_path + api_method + '?' + api_data)
    api_request.add_header("User-Agent", "Kraken REST API")
```

But I'm not sure what I need to change "api_domain" to in order to work with the demo-futures keys.  I'm getting "Exception: EAPI:Invalid key" when I use my API key from the demo-futures account with the

Answer (score 1):

To interact with the Sandbox/demo environment using the Kraken Python REST API, you should change the `api_domain` variable in your code to the demo environment URL. The URL for the demo environment is "https://demo-futures.kraken.com".

```py
api_domain = "https://demo-futures.kraken.com"
```

See "[The Base Clients](https://python-kraken-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.0/src/base_api/base_api.html)"

> If the sandbox environment is chosen, the keys must be generated from the demo environment's settings page: `https://demo-futures.kraken.com/settings/api`.

The standard URL for accessing the Kraken Futures API is "https://futures.kraken.com", and its endpoints can be accessed by sending HTTP requests to `https://futures.kraken.com/derivatives/api/v3`. However, for the sandbox environment, you should use the "https://demo-futures.kraken.com" domain.

Make sure the API keys you are using are generated from the sandbox environment, as the keys from the production environment will not work on the sandbox environment and vice versa.

---

The [OP Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235929/dave) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77299124/with-the-kraken-python-rest-api-how-to-interact-with-sandbox-demo-environment/77319916#comment136367657_77319916):

> I contacted Kraken support and they confirmed there is no sandbox for limit order trading (for items that are non-futures, like [ETHUSD](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/ETHUSD/ideas/?exchange=KRAKEN)).
>
> How do these guys expect people to use their platform if people can't even test it out?

Comment: Does the URL you listed permit limit buys?  I'm confused by the "futures" inclusion in the domain.  When I try a limit buy or limit sell, I get the errors, "API call failed (HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: @Dave All I know from the [support page](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024809011-API-Testing-Environment) is that "The WebSocket and REST API code on this environment is identical to the live production code in terms of the feeds/endpoints and the response structure." and "The only difference between the demo API behavior and that of the live production environment is that the base URL is not futures.kraken.com but instead demo-futures.kraken.com". Check if

Comment: I am not finding this is true, at least not with the domain "demo-futures.kraken.com."  When I try a limit buy using the "api.kraken.com" with a real key and secret, I get an "Insufficient funds" message, which is correct (since I don't have any money in the account).  Have you been able to make these calls in a demo environment using Python?

Comment: @Dave No, only reading the dccumentation like "[Does Kraken offer an API test environment?](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000919926-Does-Kraken-offer-an-API-test-environment-)" and "[API Testing Environment](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024809011-API-Testing-Environment)". It appears that the URL `"https://demo-futures.kraken.com"` is designated for testing the futures API on Kraken, not the spot trading API. Hence, "HTTP Error 405: Method Not Allowed" when attempting to execute limit buy/sell orders through this URL.

Comment: @Dave On the other hand, the spot trading API, which is what would be used for limit orders on the spot market, does not have a designated sandbox or demo environment according to the same sources. That is probably why you are able to execute a limit order (though with an "Insufficient funds" response, as expected) on the `"https://api.kraken.com"` domain with a real API key and secret.

Comment: I contacted Kraken support and they confirmed there is no sandbox for limit order trading (for items that are non-futures, like ETHUSD).  How do these guys expect people to use their platform if people can't even test it out??

Comment: @Dave I agree, that is inconvenient. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.